# Is SharePoint 2016 compatible with Windows Active Directory functional domain/forest level 2012R2?

Tags: 2016, active-directory, active-directory-import

I would like to know if there is any documentation from Microsoft stating that SharePoint 2016 is compatible with Windows Active Directory functional domain/forest level 2012R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello i found these documentations about SharePoint versions and AD and yes, AD on server 2012R2 is supported. There is only minimum version for AD and it is 2003 SP2.

- [SharePoint 2016 Installation Guide](https://collab365.community/we-go-step-by-step-installation-of-sharepoint-2016-rtm/) - direct link for AD [here](https://collab365.community/configured-domain-services-controller-and-create-users-and-groups/)
- [There are confirmation](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5bff126a-2310-49eb-87e9-857876590d3f/does-sharepoint-2010-support-ad-2016?forum=sharepointadminprevious) for SP2010 and AD2016
- [SharePoint 2013](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/0e705cad-2a7e-4209-8ab1-22c04c798383/active-directory-requirement-for-sharepoint-2016) had a minimum of "Active Directory 2003 SP2", which of course makes no sense, but that said consider Domain Controllers at a minimum of Server 2003 R2 with a forest/domain functional level of 2003 native.
- In [this manual](https://www.netiq.com/communities/cool-solutions/complete-premise-sharepoint-2016-setup-guide-simple-easy-steps-troubleshooting/) - Complete On-premise SharePoint 2016 Setup Guide, step 2: Instal AD 2012R2

I hope these posts are enough for You.

*Hope it helps!*